# Use of Regexp_contains

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to get the output "BR" and "CR" respectively for the following REGEXP_CONTAINS, but I'm getting 'BR' for both. How do i get "BR' for first one and 'CR' for second one.

CASE

```
 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Title, '(?i)saving') THEN 'BR'

 WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Title, '(?i)Life Savings') THEN 'CR'
```

END;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change order of conditions as in below example

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Title, '(?i)Life Savings') THEN 'CR'
  WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Title, '(?i)saving') THEN 'BR'
END
```

Comment: @Mikhali, thanks for the help. It works fine now. Just wanted to know, is it for the Alphabetical order? ie, Life savings is coming first than Saving.

Comment: No. Just simply those conditions are evaluated in the order you have them in your case statement. So first you put more restrictive and then less restrictive conditions